# Why do Spanish words change meaning when put in a sentence?

Tags: romance-languages, spanish, sentences

The word "ponga" means "I put" but when put in this sentence: Que solo la mire de lejito y se ponga asi" is "That he only looks at her from afar and gets like this" "Ponga" doesn't become "I put" anymore in that sentence, and I'm very confused as to why and what this is called

Comment: Isn't it both first person and third person?

Comment: Note that *que yo ponga ...* and *que el ponga ...* are both subjunctives. If the pronoun is left out, you need to use context.  The *se* is part of the context here.

Comment: It’s exceedingly common in languages with inflectional morphology that different forms of the same word have the same surface shape. Consider ‘put’ in English, which can be either base form (infinitive/imperative/present subjunctive), present tense (except third singular), past tense, or past participle. In Spanish, all verbs have the same form in the first and third singular in the present subjunctive, imperfect, conditional and past subjunctive – that’s just how Spanish verbal morphology works. So to say that _ponga_ means ‘I put’ is inaccurate: it means ‘[that] I put/[that] he put/put!’.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do <s>Spanish</s> words change meaning when put in a sentence?

Is this unique to Spanish, that one surface form can have many [senses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_sense)?

Let me put it like this:

> He [put](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put#Verb) his shares at 80.
> He is a shot [put](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put#Noun) champion.
> He sold a [put](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put#Noun).
> He is a [put](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put#Etymology_2).
> He is a [put](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put#Etymology_3).
> ...

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_articulation